# Does an Indian citizen with B1 B2 visa, need a transit visa in Australia?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, australia, syd

planning to travel Dubai to Christchurch via Sydney. Flight layover time will be 2 hrs maximum.Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa in Australia ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a visa according to Timatic  https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/olo1H3LBkm5xMlVNrR74hIbZ6yvk

Holding a B1/B2 visa is irrelevant.